# Is static IP important for Java socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets, domain-name

I am confused about 127.0.0.1 and port no for socket programming. 
If I a have a domain name then there is no importance of static ip address. Anyone please help for this.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 (127.x.x.x) is *special* well-known IP address/range: [the loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) (see also http://superuser.com/questions/255835). It is different than "an arbitrary static IP address" and it only makes sense within a local context. Machines can only directly connect to their *own* loopback.

Comment: Do not even need IP addresses/port numbers at all to do socket programming.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket Programming does not require that you only work with static IP address. You can write code using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If you know the domain name of server, you can use that as well. You can also use the dynamic IP which most internet users get.

Comment: Means i can use domain name like www.rahul.com in socket programming. Or use socket client programs like     Socket client = new Socket("www.rahul.com", portno);

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to a static IP-number directly if you want to, but normally in production a real web server such as Nginx or Apache is used for that, because they are faster, more secure, and handle headers and other parts of the HTTP standard for you. They then in turn connect to your socket.

127.0.0.1 is a special IP number also known as localhost, and is used to connect to the same machine, and is not accessible from other computers. So if you listen to 127.0.0.1 you need Nginx or similar on the same computer to forward traffic to your socket, otherwise it won't be accessible from other computers.

Answer (score 0):

Every computer connected to a network has an IP address assigned to it, whether statically or dynamically.  A server socket must be bound to this IP address on a specific port in order to accept clients.  A client connects to the server's current IP and port.

A domain name is simply a way for clients to determine the server's current IP address using a static human-readible name.  If the server's IP address changes, the server socket must be rebound, and the mapping of the domain name must be updated.

127.0.0.1, aka "localhost", is a reserved IP address that refers to the local machine.  If a server socket is bound to this IP address, it can accept clients only from the same machine.